# Prevent encode the rest call with post Method in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I am using angular js and making a restcall. But I have one variable and this variable have some value when I put this variable in service then this variable value encoded in console.

**REST CALL**

```
var rep = "CX-0138_ES48A9CA";

  Rh.all('example/demo/db ').post(" ",+JSON.stringify(rep)).then(function(resp)
  {
 
  })
```

then rep value is not exist in console url.

[image]

But when I removed **+JSON.stringify** then service(url) encoded.

```
var rep = "CX-0138_ES48A9CA";

  Rh.all('example/demo/db ').post(" ",rep).then(function(resp)
  {
 
  })
```

Encoded service in console
[image]

How can set value of rep **CX-0138_ES48A9CA** in post method.

Comment: During the post why do u want to use url variable ?

Comment: @Noman I want to send some id in rep with post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Rh.all('example/demo/db ').post({rep: encodeUriComponent(rep)}).then(function(resp)
  {

  })
```

Comment: It is prevent from encoding but in the url "rep=" is adding then hitting url will make differ.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but please see my updated answer using encodeUriComponent